# Backbone router.on event not firing from url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router

I am trying to fire a backbone event when the user inputs the URL (whatever.com)/questions/new.

my router looks like the following:

```
define(['backbone'],function(BackBone){

    var routeExtend = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
              "": "home",   
              "questions/new": 'newQuestion'
            },

        });


    var initialize = function(){

        var Router = new routeExtend();         

        Router.on('route:newQuestion', function() {             
            console.log('new question');
        });

        BackBone.history.start();           
        return Router;

    }


    return {initialize:initialize};
});
```

And if I call router.navigate within my app, the event fires fine.

However, I want to be able to fire the "on" event if "questions/new" is the initial URL given to the web browser. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you are passing in BackBone, but extend Backbone.Router in line 3, watch your case

Comment: Hi Joe please elaborate.

Comment: line 1, you are assigning the result of the require call to the variable BackBone (CamelCase)  then you use Backbone on line 3, which must be either undefined or defined globally elsewhere, but isn't the same as BackBone which you use further down.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Fixed that spelling issue. This does not fix the routing issue though, any idea if what I am asking is possible?

Answer (score 0):

you could define the function instead of router.on event

```
var routeExtend = Backbone.Router.extend({
     routes: {
         "": "home",
         "questions/new": 'newQuestion'
     },
     newQuestion: function() {
         console.log('new question');
     }
 });
```